# Images doesn't display correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have updated my code from previous questions I have asked but now the images won't display, and I don't know why exactly. What should happen is when I click one button an image should display and stay there even if it refreshes, but until another button is clicked the new image should take over and the same thing should happen, stay there even if the page refreshes until they click on another button, but no images display at all.

Here is my function:

```
var maxImages=7,i=1,v;

for(i;i=<maxImages;i++)
{
    v = sessionStorage.getItem('v'+i);
    if(v !== null) showImage(i);
}

function showImage(num)
{
    sessionStorage.setItem('v' + num, '1');
    $("#loadingImage" + num).show();
}
```

and here is my button function:

```
<input name="Failure Analysis Lab" style="white-space:normal;" 
 onclick="moveText(this.name);showImage(1);form1.submit();" 
 style="width: 272px; height: 30px;" type="button" 
 value="7QKD Failure Analysis Lab" />
```

and here is my image tag:

```
<img id="loadingImage" alt="" src="images/Overview.gif" 
 style="width:85%;; margin-bottom:3em; display:none;"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Additional info: I get no errors when I check the console but no images are being displayed.

Comment: Your mark up in image is <img id="loadingImage"... and this is how you call it via jquery: $("#loadingImage" + num).show(); ID doesn't match

Comment: I have multiple images though so i have an id = loadingImage2, 3, 4 and so on

Comment: What do `moveText()` and `showImage()` look like? Looking at your other questions: `showImage()` is never used; it looks like that should be `showImage1()`, unless you've changed something. It'd help a ton if you posted all of your code in one place (and then work only from that question, as creating multiple makes this more difficult - especially when they're working out essentially the same issues)

Comment: moveText() is just a function that takes the value of the button and puts in a text box, it doesn't nothing to the images.

Comment: Okay. Then do try `showImage1()` (unless you've renamed it between your previous questions and now)

Comment: I haven't changed the name, and I tried it and nothing happens

Comment: Then please post all of your code in a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZHRz/7/) .. I made some adjustments is this sort of what you were looking for?

Moved the click events to be handled by jQuery ... and set up data on each input to check which image it wants to display.

```
var v = sessionStorage.getItem('imageId');
if (v !== null) {
    showImage(v);
}

$("input").on("click", function () {
    var imageId = $(this).attr("imageId");
    showImage(imageId);
});

function showImage(imageId) {
    var img = $("#" + imageId);
    var hidingImg = sessionStorage.getItem('imageId');
    $("#" + hidingImg).hide();
    sessionStorage.setItem('imageId', imageId);
    img.show();
}
```

Comment: nearly, what i want is when they click another button the previous image closes and the new image displays automatically

Comment: well then your sessionStorage variables shouldn't depend on an id .. they would likely depend on just a name and when you call showImage it first retrieves the sessionStorage variable hide that .. show the next and store the shown image's id. See the updated code.

Comment: I am just wondering How do I specify what image each button outputs from the way you did it? so I want button5 to output loadingimage2 and button3 to output loadingimage8

Comment: first thing I did was set up a way for the button to identify which image it will display ... and that depends on you ... will the input buttons have a special attribute with the id/name of the image they are displaying or will it be set up in the data of the button via jquery or will you have an array in jquery which identified the button id's with the image's id ... it's all up to you.

Comment: ya the way I originally wanted to this was for the input buttons have a special attribute with the id/name of the image they are displaying

Comment: then just do it like that .. I updated the fiddle I added an imageId attribute to each input which stores the id of the image it should show ..

Comment: I updated my code to the new function and my button's onclick event i do showImage(loadingImage), but nothing is display, is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I got the image to display but now the issue is that it is now blocking the form1.submit()

Comment: never mind actually that was just a syntax error on my part, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work the way you think (from your comments). What goes after the `#` has to *exactly* match an element ID. You'd have to create `<img id="loadingImage2">`, `<img id="loadingImage3">`, etc. for that selector to work as you intend.

`$("#loadingImage" + num)` when `num = 2`, for example, creates the selector `#loadingImage2`. If there's not an element with attribute `id="loadingImage2"`, this line will have no effect. You can call `show()`, and jQuery will do its best to show that element - but the element you want to show doesn't exist.

So assuming that you have multiple loadingImages, change your HTML to something like this:

```
<img class="loadingImage" src="image1.jpg">
<img class="loadingImage" src="image2.jpg">
<!-- And so on -->
```

Then in your jQuery, select and show all elements of class loadingImage with `$(".loadingImage").show();`

Comment: I have added the divs but still nothing displays

Comment: Sorry - those should have said `img`, not `div`. Updated

Comment: Do I have to change anything on my button click cause still nothing displays